# <IDENTITY IMPERSONATE=TRUE> & Application_Start event

Tags: application-start, impersonation

So - after much research, it appears that the < identity impersonate=true > only works AFTER the Application_Start event fires.

Does anyone know any workaround to this problem?  I have an application which needs to create the database when the application first starts.  The user that the IIS website runs as has the appropriate permissions to do in a way that the APP_POOL user SPECIFICALLY DOES NOT have.

My current HACK solution is to put (peudo code)

```
static bool AppInitialized = false;
void Session_Start() {
   if (!AppInitialized) {
     AppInitialized=true;
     InitializeApp();
   }
}
```

impersonate=true will be "in effect" by the time a specific session is starting - and so this WORKS, but seems silly since I'm basically re-creating the behavior of the Application_Start event.  Seems like there MUST be a more elegant solution to this problem - no?

Answer (score 0):

That is strange --
I have this entry in my web.config file:

```
<identity impersonate="true" password="blarhg" userName="thisuser"/>
```

And when I check the identity on the Application_Start() event, it's giving me "thisuser".

Is that not correct?

Comment: Yes - that is correct.  The problem is when you are trying to detect the authenticated user's identity.  In other words, if you specify a username/password in the identity field, it is available during the Application Start event.  If want the identity of the authenticated user, it is available at Session_Start but not during Application_Start.  During the Application_Start event, the APP_POOL identity is used, which is PRECISELY the user I do NOT want to give access to my database...   Does that make sense?

Comment: It makes sense, but i'm trying to think of how/why you'd want to do that lol =)
Where you thinking you'd login to your app to start the application?
The APP POOL will recycle every so often (I think default is 90min.), so the application will stop & start multiple times throughout the day.
If there is a certain process you want to start when the app starts (and the user doing it is important), you should probably manually authenticate a user/account and run your process and then release the impersonation.
Hope this helps